# UICollectionView Approach for having expandable comments/replies

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have a collectionView as the following :

[image]

`UICollectionView` with multiple sections, section 2 is comments and it has rows of each comment,
now I want when i press a comment it displays its replies.. **and hide ALL other opened replies**

- I tried appending replies in collectionView array ( Appending below the actual comment index )

I'm good until i want to collapse the replies again ? I did the following :

- I saved the original array without appended replies and reused it for everytime i append replies, so it basically adds replies to a clean array

but the issue here with identifying where to append replies (which index) because the index is returned wrong after the append of first replies

TL;DR what's the best approach for doing this in UICollectionView using objective c?

Answer (score 0):

A better way which is alittlebit harder is to use nested collection view,a collection view in a collection view,meaning in each cell you also put a collectionview